# CoreData generated classes are public in framework

Tags: swift, core-data

I work on framework written on swift with CoreData model. I want to keep core data generated classes private.

How to keep them private?

Comment: Why not generate them manually and remove the `public` access level for the class?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yea, probably that's only the way to do it. I just don't want to have a lot of classes only for this thing.

Comment: Who will use this framework and how much of an issue is it to have them public? You might want to weight the extra work and maintenance involved vs just leaving them public.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I did as you said in first comment. generated and remove public, would be nice to have checkbox in Xcode, simply switch on and off this thing. I will do create feature request for Xcode on bugreport.apple.com.